# Custom Font Issue in Android Q 10.0 update cant able to use downloaded ttf file font in EditText and Text view

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts

I have tried all the option mentioned in below links
https://medium.com/programming-lite/using-custom-font-as-resources-in-android-app-6331477f8f57
https://medium.com/@suragch/using-a-custom-font-in-your-android-app-cc4344b977a5

But still, App gets crash cant able to use custom font **Error inflating class EditText** but if I remove custom font it works fine

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this by splitting my font resource file into two based on API version, where api 26+ just uses the `android:font*` attributes and below api 26 we use the `app:font*` attributes:

app/src/main/res/font/source_sans_pro.xml

```
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- light -->
    <font
            app:font="@font/source_sans_pro_light"
            app:fontStyle="normal"
            app:fontWeight="300" />

    <font
            app:font="@font/source_sans_pro_light_italic"
            app:fontStyle="normal"
            app:fontWeight="300" />

    <!-- normal -->
    <font
            app:font="@font/source_sans_pro_regular"
            app:fontStyle="normal"
            app:fontWeight="400"/>
    <font
            app:font="@font/source_sans_pro_regular_italic"
            app:fontStyle="italic"
            app:fontWeight="400"
            />

    <!-- bold -->
    <font
            app:font="@font/source_sans_pro_semibold"
            app:fontStyle="normal"
            app:fontWeight="500"/>
    <font
            app:font="@font/source_sans_pro_semibold_italic"
            app:fontStyle="italic"
            app:fontWeight="500"/>
```

app/src/main/res/font-v26/source_sans_pro.xml

```xml
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
    <!-- light -->
    <font
            android:font="@font/source_sans_pro_light"
            android:fontStyle="normal"
            android:fontWeight="300" />

    <font
            android:font="@font/source_sans_pro_light_italic"
            android:fontStyle="italic"
            android:fontWeight="300" />

    <!-- normal -->
    <font
            android:font="@font/source_sans_pro_regular"
            android:fontStyle="normal"
            android:fontWeight="400" />
    <font
            android:font="@font/source_sans_pro_regular_italic"
            android:fontStyle="italic"
            android:fontWeight="400" />

    <!-- bold -->
    <font
            android:font="@font/source_sans_pro_semibold"
            android:fontStyle="normal"
            android:fontWeight="500" />
    <font
            android:font="@font/source_sans_pro_semibold_italic"
            android:fontStyle="italic"
            android:fontWeight="500" />   
</font-family>
```

I haven't tracked it down to an Android Q update or if it's a bug in one of the newer androidx versions yet. I believe this is a regression or new bug in appcompat 1.2.0-alpha03 or material 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problem ,what I did is - remove the xml file and directly use the font name(without extention) which was in ttf . example -

```
android:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa_bold"

android:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa_italic"
```

Answer (score 0):

If we use EditText font option throughs error in Q update so use AppCompactEditText to accept fort constraint directly in XML page